# Cancel an OnTouchListener on elapsed time

Tags: java, android

```
    image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {   
                String serverResponse = "";
                JSONObject responseToJSON = null;
                    try {
                        //if we have Internet connection
                        if(NetworkRequest.hasNetworkConnection(MyActivity.this)){
                            //download the server response
                            serverResponse = NetworkRequest.getUrlData(array.get(i));
                            responseToJSON = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
                            String individualDescription = responseToJSON.getString("Description");                 
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                 return false;
             } 
    });
```

I have the aforementioned code. Where I set an OnClickListener on an image. So, when I will click on the image i override the onTouch method. Then I check if I have internet connection. If I have I try to download a content from the internet. That I want to do is to have something as a Timer and check if  the following line of code

```
NetworkRequest.getUrlData(array.get(i))
```

needs more than 2 seconds to download the content. If needs more that 2 seconds to download the content, I want to cancel both downloading and the OnTouchListener. Is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Be aware that this piece of code should give you a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Time to download is an approximate value and cannot be calculated exactly. Do you already have the code for calculating how long a download will take?

Comment: @m0skit0 No I don't have it. To be honest, I don't know how to do what I want. I just need a suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29). Assign to a variable the system time, then check is this time is greater that the last one + 2000 and here you go :-).

Cheers

Comment: You did not answer the question. How do you cancel downloading? And the listener? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't see how you can do it with this implementation. I think that you should use a controlling process, which will be executed after two seconds, because once you start the download, you need a threaded process to see if it's taking more than 2 secs.